# Display Default Value Decode Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, decode

I am attempting to set values to zero if a user does not exist in one of my tables. Currently, I am using decode to count the number of users that meet a certain criteria and then display the result.

```
SELECT T.D_CODE, 
       T.C_NO, 
       SUM(DECODE(t.Value, 'A', 1, 0)) AS FirstValue, 
       SUM(DECODE(t.Value, 'B', 1, 0)) AS SecondValue, 
       SUM(DECODE(t.Value, 'C', 1, 0)) AS ThirdValue, 
       SUM(DECODE(t.Value, 'F', 1, 0)) AS LastValue
  FROM Table T, 
       Table OtherTable S
 WHERE T.T_SSN = S.SSN(+) 
   AND T.D_CODE = 'INF'
 GROUP BY t.D_CODE, 
          T.C_NO;
```

The issue is that I have a `third table (TT)` that has additional values in it.  If `TT` has a value that is not present in `Table T`, then I need to display that record with 0's for all of the Decode values.

Required output would look something like:

`D_CODE, C_NO, FirstValue, SecondValue, ThirdValue, LastValue
INF     600       2            0           0          0
INF     501       0            0           1          0
INF     400       0            0           0          0`

Where `INF 400` does not exist in Table t, only in Table TT

Any suggestions?

Comment: A sample data and required output would certainly help

Comment: @JorgeCampos sure, posted required output

Comment: I think I got it, but I'm not entirely sure, so I will provide you an answer and if it is not what you want you tell me in comments. Also, if it is not you will have to add some sample data from the three tables that meet your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are filtering the users by `T.D_CODE = 'INF'` which means that any user that does not met that criteria will not come at all in the results. So, for what I understood of your question you need this:

```
SELECT T.D_CODE, 
       T.C_NO, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.D_CODE = 'INF' AND t.Value = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FirstValue, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.D_CODE = 'INF' AND t.Value = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  AS SecondValue, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.D_CODE = 'INF' AND t.Value = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  AS ThirdValue, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.D_CODE = 'INF' AND t.Value = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  AS LastValue
  FROM Table T
         LEFT JOIN Table OtherTable S 
           ON T.T_SSN = S.SSN
         LEFT JOIN AnotherTable TT
              ON T.T_SSN = TT.SSN
 GROUP BY t.D_CODE, 
          T.C_NO;
```

Since you didn't provide any more details about your `TT` table I just guessed the relation between it and the `T` table.

Side note: Always use the SQL ANSI [LEFT ]JOINs style.

**ALSO** Note that for your current query and current fetched fields tables `S` and `TT` are totally irrelevant, unless you didn't explain it right.